# Split feature class based on number of records arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, splitting

I am looking for a way to split a feature class into multiple feature classes based on the number of records, probably using python. E.g first 100, next 100, etc. I have so far only seen options to split by attributes.

Comment: Add a new field, calculate it to !Objectid! / 100. Use this new field in Split By Attribute.

Comment: @klewis That would give me a feature class for each record. I want each featureclass to have 100 features. E.g feature class 1 has 100 features, feature class 2 has the next 100, etc.

Comment: @ketar Have you tried that solution?  Please don't say it doesn't work without trying it.  Works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Midavalo I have arcgis 10.3 so no access to the splitbyattributes tool. But I use a python script to split by attributes. Using the !Objectid! / 100 gives  a feature class for each unique value. That's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you used to split by attributes.  Calculating `!OBJECTID! / 100` should give you 100 records with the same ObjectID value, so when splitting by attributes the calculated value should put 100 records into each output feature class.

Comment: @Midavalo that assumes the ObjectIDs are sequential; that no features have been deleted.

Comment: @Bjorn There are ways around that if that is an issue.  Calculating a new sequential field for example.

Comment: @Midavalo The new field that I was calculating was set to type double. I have created a new one set to integer and that seems to do it. Thank you.

Comment: The USGS offers a SplitByAttribute tool for ArcGIS 10.3. https://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html

Comment: I attempted to use the above code that Midavalo provided and it just copied the same number of records. Anyone have any thoughts on how to get the code to select the next set of items in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @klewis mentioned you could use the Split By Attribute feature:

Esri [provides](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) the following sample code that you could use as mentioned:

```
# Name: SplitByAttributes.py  
# Description: Use the SplitByAttributes tool to split a feature class by 
# unique values.

# Import required modules
import arcpy

#Set local variables  
in_feature_class = 'c:/data/base.gdb/ecology'  
target_workspace = 'c:/data/output.gdb'  
fields = ['REGION', 'ECO_CODE']  

arcpy.SplitByAttributes_analysis(in_feature_class, target_workspace, fields)
```

Comment: That would give me a feature class for each record. I want each feature class to have 100 features. E.g feature class 1 has 100 features, feature class 2 has the next 100, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The following code will split the features into groups of 100 (or the value set in `outputNum`) then copy them to individual feature classes.

```
import arcpy

outputNum = 100
outputFCName = "OutputFC"

def listSplit(myList, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(myList), n):
        yield myList[i:i + n]

arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\gis\se\gisse.gdb"
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("RandomPoints")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
fList = list()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, "OID@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        fList.append(row[0])

listGroup = listSplit(fList, outputNum)

for x in listGroup:
    lyr.setSelectionSet("NEW", x)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr, arcpy.CreateUniqueName(outputFCName))
```