# Breaking up geodatabase table with more than 1000 records into multiple tables with 1000 records maximum in each using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, lock

I'm trying to use the arcpy.da.SearchCursor and arcpy.da.InsertCursor objects to scan through a table with more than 1000 records and create multiple geodatabase tables with a maximum of 1000 records in each. These tables will be used to pass through to ESRI's geocoding service.

For example, I have a geodatabase table with 2500 rows. I need to break this table into 3 tables, two tables containing 1000 records and another table containing 500 records (this can be hard-coded, but I need it to be dynamic as it is part of a nightly script). Therefore, if I had 4030 records, I would need 5 tables, etc.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(well_address, "*") as cursor:
    tab_list = [] #this list is used for a later process in the workflow
    rec_cnt = 0 #count the number of records
    table_count = 1
    while rec_cnt != int(arcpy.GetCount_management(well_address).getOutput(0)):
        counter = 0
        table = arcpy.CreateTable_management(final_gdb, "addrTab_" + str(table_count), template = well_address)
        insert = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table, "*")
        for row in cursor:
            insert.insertRow(row)
            counter += 1
            rec_cnt += 1
            if counter > 999:
                table_count += 1
                break
            else:
                print("Moving to next record for the table...")
        tab_list.append(table)
```

The problem with this script is when i execute it, it will populate the first 2 tables with 1000 records each, however the last table is empty...when I run arcpy.GetCount_management on the third table it says it has 500 records, but the geodatabase table is empty. If I execute the code snippet again (using a different starting number for the table_count variable) it will actually write the rows to the last table called.

For example, when I run the code the first time, I get two tables with 1000 records each and a third table that is empty. Then if I change the table_count variable to 10 and run the code again, table_3 fills with the 500 records from before and the tables 10 and 11 are populated each with 1000 records. However, table 12 is empty. This pattern continues on as I keep changing the table_count variable and executing. It's acting as if the insert statement is not commited but I'm using with, which should not cause any open cursor problems.

Comment: Add `table_count += 1` before you break when your count reaches 1000. That way, it will create the next table.

Comment: Duplicate https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243449/split-feature-class-based-on-number-of-records-arcpy?

Comment: Perhaps write to temp table in memory and dump it to disk table when get to 1000. Similar thing happened to me.

Comment: Deleting insert cursor might help as well

Comment: I changed the location of the table counter and that cleaned up the table_counter variable to be 3 instead of 4. Thanks Feztler! I tried to dump the results to disk, but when I did it created a blank table with 2 other tables with 1000 records each.

Comment: When it creates the 3 tables in ArcCatalog (two with 1000 records, one with 0 records) and I go to delete them from my geodatabase, it won't delete the last one, because there is a lock on the table. It's as if the results are floating in memory and when I execute the code again it writes the results to the last table and releases the lock. Is there something in the updated code that could cause this?

Comment: It would be alot easier to just select 1000 rows at a time using one searchcursor and then copy rows tool.'

Comment: That would be a descent method if I had a table that had a record count that was divisible by 1000. I'm not sure you would get the remainder using that method. I'm curious, it's worth investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can list OIDs, split list into chunks of 1000,1000,...,and whatever number is left, and use an SQL query to select and create tables using TableSelect_analysis:

```
import arcpy,os
input_table = r'C:\data.gdb\table'
output_workspace = r'C:\outdata.gdb'

def chunks(l, n): #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

oidfield = arcpy.Describe(input_table).OIDFieldName
all_oids = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_table,oidfield)]

count = 1
for chunk in chunks(all_oids,1000):
    sql = """{0} IN({1})""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(input_table,oidfield),','.join([str(r) for r in chunk]))
    arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(input_table, os.path.join(output_workspace,"Table_{0}".format(count)), sql)
    count+=1
```

[image]

Comment: This is  great idea! The only issue is I need the output to be a geodatabase table to pass to ESRI's gecoding service using the arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_geocoding tool.

Comment: @RobertHadsell, Why is that an issue? (I have no experience of geocoding. )

Comment: no worries! This method would work had I built the logic in the script to handle a list rather than a geodatabase table. However, using the arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_gecoding tool, the input parameter is a geodatabase table/table view. Therefore, I would have to write the lists to a geodatabase table in order to get the script to work.

Comment: It is creating geodatabase tables

Comment: you're correct, this script does create geodatabase tables! I reran the code this morning and got the same result. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RobertHadsell nice, could you accept my answer with the checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The insert cursor was in-fact keeping a lock on the last set of records, so I changed the syntax such that the with statement would ensure there was no lock on the cursor. Once I made the change, it gave me three tables, one with 500 records and 2 with 1000 records each.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(well_address, "*") as cursor:
tab_list = [] #will store all tables in here to be merged later on in the script
rec_cnt = 0 #record counter for while loop condition...total will equal total number of records in the source table
table_count = 1 #counter used to alter the table name for each new table
while rec_cnt != int(arcpy.GetCount_management(well_address).getOutput(0)): #check to see if the record count is less than the number of records in the table
    counter = 0 #counter used to keep track of the number of records in each child table
    table = arcpy.CreateTable_management(final_gdb, "addrTab_" + str(table_count), template = well_address) #create the table to hold the records
    #insert = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table, "*") #create insert cursor to insert the row from the original table into the newly created table
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table, "*") as insert:
        for row in cursor:
            insert.insertRow(row)
            counter += 1
            rec_cnt += 1
            if counter > 999:
                table_count += 1 #increase the number for the table after exiting the for loop
                break
            else:
                print("Inserting record for table: " + str(table_count))
        tab_list.append(table)
```

Thank you all for the help, I hope this will be useful to someone else! These tables are useful for ESRI's geocoding service, as they only allow a maximum of 1000 records per table.